# How can I get Capistrano to include .htaccess files in deployments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to get Capistrano deploying my web app.  I'm deploying a php app using remote_cache from a git repo to a Linux host via a Windows computer.  Everything is deploying okay except that it doesn't copy over the .htaccess files.  I'm new to Capistrano and Ruby, so any pointers would be helpful!

Capistrano 2.5.18 with Ruby 1.8.6 on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, please see http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/browse_thread/thread/c3f43079a8e221b3/a714ca05bc5eb1d1

Answer (score 1):

remove htaccess first manually, then remove/symlink every time you deploy

```
  desc "remove .htaccess"
  task :htaccess do
    run "rm #{path}/.htaccess"
    run "ln #{path}/.htaccess #{release_path}/public/.htaccess"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, but I'm on site5 so the contents of your htaccess file would probably be different; I added the following to the bottom of my deploy.rb file:

```
after "deploy:create_symlink", "MYAPPNAME:htaccess_setup"


namespace :MYAPPNAME do
  task :htaccess_setup, :roles => :app do
    htaccess = "PATHTOMYPUBLICDIR/.htaccess"
    run "if [ ! -f #{htaccess} ]; then echo 'PassengerEnabled On' > #{htaccess}; echo 'PassengerAppRoot #{current_path}' >> #{htaccess}; echo '.htaccess created'; else echo '.htaccess already exists (untouched)'; fi"
  end
end
```